# How to integrate Pusher with rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher, gritter

i can`t integrate Pusher with my rails app

there is any example or good tutorial for that ?

www.pusher.com

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem

Comment: look at their README and let us know if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: i`m beginner with rails ... the problem that I don`t know where he puts the Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is using pusher as a heroku addon but should be easy to understand anyway https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pusher-in-app-notifications